# Как определить количество присланных фотографий в telegraf?

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot, telegram, telegraf

По ctx.message.media_group_id я могу определить, что фотографий за раз было отправлено несколько. Но как понять, сколько именно? Нужно обработать каждую фотографию, и только после этого перейти к следующему шагу сцены.

Answer (score 0):

если нужны просто аудио видео -- telegraf-media-group
если нужны еще файлы -- открой их либу -- индекс и добавь значение document

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]